# Create additional default parameters for cmdlet definitions

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

When you create a Powershell script or function, you are able to add the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute in order to gain certain default parameters for use (e.g. `-Verbose`, `-Debug`, etc.) without having to define them yourself. In some cases you can add additional parameters to `CmdletBinding`, like `SupportsShouldProcess` or `ConfirmImpact` to further add additional supported parameters or change the cmdlet behavior.

Is it possible to define your own `CmdletBindings` for use within a module?

Comment: my understanding is that those are added by the PoSh engine. if that is the case, then you likely can't. **_that is only my guess, tho._** [*grin*]

Comment: The source for the `CmdletBindingAttribute` can [be found here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/Attributes.cs#L417).  It's not marked `sealed`, so you could expand on it yourself in your script and use the new attribute.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 You could, but it wouldn't have any effect :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to define your own `CmdletBindings` for use within a module?

## No

Not in a script anyways :)

The `CmdletBinding` attribute properties are processed by [this method in the `CommandMetadata` API](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/6dda2308fe5a970b0471da3c54d3db06e084724f/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/CommandMetadata.cs#L724-L758) immediately prior to compilation of whatever scriptblock or function has it, so you'd have to rewrite parts of the language engine itself in order to modify its behavior.

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to use `Add-Type` to define your own attribute and `Invoke-Expression` to compile on-demand?  It's possible to do this with `class` definitions in the language.

Comment: Sure, you can compile all the attributes you want - but it wouldn't have any effect on the command runtime, like `[CmdletBinding()]` does :)